# snprintf() in C treats the lowest two bytes of the destination String not individually

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I wanted to write a little program which should reverse characters of a string using the `snprintf()` function in the following way. That's where I noticed something strange.

```
int main() {

    char dest[5] = "";
    char source[5] = "abc";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        char c = source[i];
        snprintf(dest, 5, "%c%s", c, dest);  //here, the current character gets appended in front
                                             //of the String "dest" using snprintf() "recursively"
    }
}
```

What the program should output: `cba`
The actual output: `ccba`

When debugging the program you can see that the lowest two bytes (`dest[0]` and `dest[1]`) always carry the same information.

*Does someone know why this happens and how to prevent this?*
If I don't use `dest` twice in the argument but instead use a temporary buffer like: `snprintf(temporary, 5, "%c%s", c, dest)` and `snprintf(dest, 5, "%s", temporary)` directly afterwards everything works as expected.

Comment: You cannot print a string onto itself: If `dest` is the first argument, i.e. the string you want to print to, you can't use it as any of the arguments after the format.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` reads the *nul-byte* in `"abc"` as `c` and then (prepends) it before the string in `snprintf(dest, 5, "%c%s", c, dest);`. (and yes, as @MOehm identifies, if the strings overlap, you invoke *Undefined Behavior*)

Comment: You are misusing the word "recursively".  Your code has nothing to do with recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is not allowed by the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  From section 7.21.6.5 regarding the `snprintf` function:

> The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf , except that the
>   output is written into an array (specified by argument s ) rather than
>   to a stream.  If n is zero, nothing is written, and s may  be  a  null
>   pointer.   Otherwise,  output  characters  beyond  the n-1 st  are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character
>   is written at the end of  the  characters  actually  written  into 
>   the  array.  **If copying  takes  place  between  objects that overlap,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

So you can't have the destination be one of the sources.  You need to write to a temp string.

Answer (score 1):

If the source and destination overlap, `memmove` can be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char dest[5] = "";
    char source[5] = "abc";
    size_t len = strlen ( source);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        memmove ( &dest[1], &dest[0], len);//move len bytes in array of [5]
        dest[0] = source[i];//set first byte
        dest[len] = 0;//ensure zero terminator
        printf ( "%s\n", dest);
    }
}
```

If recursion is desired then this can be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t strreverse(char *str, size_t index, char *dest) {
    char ch = str[index];
    if(str[index] =='\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    index = strreverse ( str, index + 1, dest);//recursion
    dest[index] = ch;
    return index + 1;
}

int main ( void) {
    char text[] = "abc";
    char result[sizeof text] = "";
    strreverse ( text, 0, result);
    printf("%s\n", text);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```